# Plancherel and characters

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group (non compact) and $\mu$ a Haar measure on $\hat{G}$ given by the Plancherel Theorem. Suppose $f\in L^2(G)$. I would like to write a formula as
$$
f=\int_{\hat{G}} \gamma(\cdot) \hat{f}(\gamma)d\mu(\gamma)
$$
in $L^2(G)$. What is allowed?

Comment: I think you need to modify Q1, because on a non-compact group, characters never lie in $L^p(G)$ for $p<\infty$.